# Can you modify a loaded SVG background-image with CSS?

Tags: css, svg, background-image

We're using SVGs for the first time for our mobile HTML5 based app sprites file (they make dealing with retina an other screen size differences easy).

I know generated SVGs can be manipulated directly (as they are text files) but can one modify an SVG asset (in this case, a background image loaded via the CSS) via CSS or scripting?

For instance, can we load an all-black SVG object, and then change it to white?

Comment: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/svg-and-css.html

Comment: You can do it for inline SVG: http://jsfiddle.net/j7dvC/2/

Answer (score 6):

You can't access the DOM of the SVG file if it's loaded as an image (either through `img` or `background-image`). You can't style it via CSS either.

If you intend to do these kind of manipulations you should append the SVG to a `div`. You   should still be able to perform sprite-like manipulations to that div. You will be able to style it via CSS or javascript.

---

The SVG should be inlined. You can copy and paste the SVG into the div that used to contain `background-image` or load it there through an ajax request.

Instead of animating `background-position` you can animate with `left` or `-webkit-transform: translate(...)`.

Comment: Can you explain the second part? What do you mean append it to the div?

Comment: Thanks! How would one use it as a sprite sheet, however, when inline? Can you mask portions of an inline SVG?

Comment: Just add a parent div with `overflow: hidden`

Comment: Thanks, Duopixel. That makes perfect sense for sprite usage. I'm still a bit confused about how to add the SVG to the DOM. By 'inlined' do you mean I should be using an actual SVG tag in the HTML itself? I think that would technically work, but is bit impractical for our needs. Oh well. It was worth experimenting a bit!