# Change SVG fill color in :before or :after CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, pseudo-element

I have a SVG graphic put like this:

```
a::before { content: url(filename.svg); }
```

When I hover over the  tag, I really want the SVG to change the fill color, without loading a new SVG file, as I have now:

```
a:hover::before { content: url(filename_white.svg); }
```

Is this possible to achieve using JavaScript, jQuery or just pure CSS that I am not aware of?

Thanks.

Comment: Maniupolating `:before` and/or `:after` pseudo-elements is not possible via JavaScript. They don't exist in the DOM.

Comment: Not sure, but maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20767413/703717) will help you

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Using the `content` property generates (non-exposed) markup functionally equvialent to an svg in an <img> element.

You cannot apply style to elements inside the svg document because:

1. styles are not allowed to cascade across documents
2. when using <img> (or `content`, or any css image property that references svg) the svg document is not exposed by the browsers due to security concerns

Similar questions, but for `background-image` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360723/specify-an-svg-as-a-background-image-and-also-style-the-svg-in-css) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13391873/can-you-modify-a-loaded-svg-background-image-with-css).

So, to do what you want you must get around the two points above somehow. There are various options for doing that, e.g using inline svg, using filters (applied to the <img>) or generating different svg files (or data URIs), as in your question.

Answer (score 163):

The accepted answer is incorrect, this is actually possible by applying a workaround with an **SVG mask** and background-color:

```css
p:after {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  -webkit-mask: url(https://gh.max.ax/heart.svg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
  mask: url(https://gh.max.ax/heart.svg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
  -webkit-mask-size: cover;
  mask-size: cover;
}

.red:after {
  background-color: red;
}

.green:after {
  background-color: green;
}

.blue:after {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p class="red">red heart</p>
<p class="green">green heart</p>
<p class="blue">blue heart</p>
```

You're not actually modifying the SVG DOM itself, you're just changing the background color. That way, you could even use images or gradients as background.

---

### Update

<strike>As MisterJ mentioned, [this feature is sadly not widely supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-masks).</strike>

After six years, the support for prefixed use has risen to [97%](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-masks).

Comment: I think you should update with the support for this method (http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-masks) 
You need to be ok with dropping some browsers along the way if you want to go for this one.

Comment: It's actually even lower than 88%. The partial support in browsers doesn't support the feature you're using. Firefox for instance doesn't support it.

Comment: Works great and you can fallback to a Unicode symbol in the content attribute (or use fontawesome)

Comment: content:'' does not seem to be necessary.

Comment: @coops glad I could help someone :)

Comment: Thanks! It helped me as well. The accepted answer might not be incorrect as it is answered in 2014.

Comment: This worked for me, thank you! Just point out that SVG doesn't show up if it does not have *fill* property set in the code.

Comment: This is brilliant. Content fallback works beautifully. Nice little trick is to set the background-color to currentColor, if you need to match the text :D

Answer (score 9):

A technique similar to [@lmaooooo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42317014/725866) without setting `display: inline-block`. This is useful in phrasing content when you want to preserve `display: inline` to ensure the `:after` content doesn't wrap to a new line independent of the preceding text content.

Also uses clip-path to prevent the background-color from leaking in Safari (the usefulness of this depends on the image/line-height/etc).

```css
a[target="_blank"]:after {
  background-color: currentColor;
  content: "";
  padding: 0 0.5em;
  margin: 0 0.125rem;
  -webkit-mask-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 2048 2048'%3E%3Cpath d='M1792 256v640h-128V475l-851 850-90-90 850-851h-421V256h640zm-512 1007h128v529H256V640h529v128H384v896h896v-401z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  mask-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 2048 2048'%3E%3Cpath d='M1792 256v640h-128V475l-851 850-90-90 850-851h-421V256h640zm-512 1007h128v529H256V640h529v128H384v896h896v-401z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask-position: center;
  mask-position: center;
  clip-path: padding-box inset(0.28125em 0);
}
```

```html
Lorem ipsum sumit dolar <a href="#" target="_blank">hello world</a>
```

Answer (score 6):

There is another way to do it.
You can make it happen by playing with filters.

Simply add svg url in content and play with hue-rotate to change the color.

According to [CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/?search=hue-rotate) It is supported by all popular broswers.

```css
p:after {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  content: url(https://gh.max.ax/heart.svg);
}

.red:after {
  filter: hue-rotate(14deg);
}

.green:after {
  filter: hue-rotate(120deg);
}

.blue:after {
  filter: hue-rotate(210deg);
}

.black:after {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

```html
<p class="red">red heart</p>
<p class="green">green heart</p>
<p class="blue">blue heart</p>
<p class="black">black heart</p>
```

Comment: Seems highly flexible. I used filter: invert(100%); to flip black to white. Thanks!

Comment: Seems impractical and risky when attempting to use existing color systems (e.g. branding).