# Fill color based on parent?

Tags: html, css, svg, sass, path

```css
&--negative {
  color: red;

  &::before {
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 1.2em;
    height: 1.2em;
    vertical-align: -15%;
    content: url(
      "data:image/svg+xml, 
      <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='red' viewBox='0 0 18 18'><path d='M5 8l4 4 4-4z'/></svg>");
  }
}
```

By having the code above, we can add a svg `before` content, which works great. My question is it seems like `fill='currentColor'` isnt really working? Ultimately I wish to make svg fill color based on parent, which in above case, color coming from `&--negative` class

**UPDATES**

I've created a [codepen](https://codepen.io/isaaclem90/pen/pobqRrR?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=dc489e1c7a384a3b331f627a728efd64d1725571-1605169802-0-AeJNRhlyx3VDu6CQ5MviqSgdDPlsFpGO92lZGYYey1DSqxi7ZJVEUx5UGlmVciJtt3Qq9jOgUbcIWbXdEa9hOWD19zkVzAFPIsDcGbvt_8Nqqbb6GC2eOyEC4uUOu2UgqAr0lb4U9sgvyL_osM9RgwrUwxIVd1PGVnnAOThMBuYgRPNN-8DAbVhVO5Yit_gUEU32wDcLLKQf667l8q1c2zxdYvy5sUo-EDbH8PLR9ldr23z5lJCsu4OHQ75xmSYE6Cf5mi6kM3SnhPd0dJMTV-ujRA0q6zf1Q0EIRnrT3g39TOEyPjF69nwpT7OplUqoJqB5VGrsIukdziH-nFaZdx4) as code sample, if you noticed I've changed to `fill='currentColor'`

Comment: Please provide more detailed example (with HTML code). You can always get parent element attributes using javascript (using parentNode and parentElement to move up in heiararchy).

Comment: @MattSergejRinc: hence my question never tag javascript

Comment: @MattSergejRinc: As requested, created a reproducible example at codepen

Comment: the SVG is self contained when called using url(), you cannot change its content from the outside

Comment: Check the answer and possible workaround here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21509982/2103539

Comment: @MattSergejRinc: Indeed that's the solution I was looking for. Thank you so much for your help!